# Form check as a whole

Tags: php, html, forms

Hello I'm trying to get back into coding and I've hit a problem that I need some help with. I've created a form with HTML5 so it has the built in required fields and i can get this to post to a database but I currently have the POST on a different page so that I can just have words saying Submit complete but currently you can just go to that submit page over and over and it will just send off blank fields to my database so I wanted to check the post as a whole to see if the whole thing is empty then not submit but I don't know if this is the best way to do it.
thanks if you need my current PHP just shout and ill put it on.

Comment: so,  you going to keep that form all to yourself? A: use a conditional `empty()` and `isset()`.

Comment: the form is being posted to a database for later use but ive got this code but it seems to still check the values one by one.   if(empty($time_event) || ($project) || ($event) || ($happened) || ($about_it) || ($reporter) || ($organisation) || ($trackside) || ($location) || ($number) || ($yes_rules) || ($life_rules) || ($feedback) || ($email) || ($region))

Comment: you're not expecting everything after `empty($time_event)` to be populated as also checking for emptyness, are you? If so, that isn't how it works. You'd be best using a `foreach` then, or set in an array etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all validate your form fields with Javascript or Jquery validation for client side validation. Its very easy, you can use jquery validation plugin eg. 
[Jquery Form Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)


For Server side validation you can use php functions like `isset($_POST['field_name'])` and `!empty($_POST['field_name'])`

For PHP form validation please visit the link for reference :
 [PHP Form Validation](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp)